# How to comfortably read full-width text on website?

Tags: browser

Recently, I stumbled on  [this paper](https://www.msu.edu/user/abbottb/formal.htm). Because I haven't found a PDF version, I tried to read it from the website. If the browser is on full width, then it is very uncomfortable to read. So I re-sized my browser to get some acceptable line lengths, but it is still not satisfactory. One possible solution would be a browser plugin, but I could not find anything suitable. Anybody got a good solution for that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the [**Readable**](http://readable.tastefulwords.com/) bookmarklet. You can customize how it shows the text, all you have to do is click on the bookmark and the text will be reformatted as you please.

Result:

[image: Readable page]

There are similar add-ons that offer the same functionality:

- Readability ([Firefox, Chrome](http://www.readability.com/addons))
- CleanPages ([Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/cleanpages/)), a port of Readability
- iReader ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ireader/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppelffpjgkifjfgnbaaldcehkpajlmbc))

Comment: thanks a lot! very quick and very helpful. readable is wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Safari 5, it's already included and available on many web pages from the address bar (which also indicates that the feature is available) or the menubar: *View » Show Reader* (`Cmd-Shift-R`).

[image]

It looks quite nice, and you can directly print from it, and set font size independent of the web page's. Press the button or menu item again, and you return to the regular web page view.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it appears to be not activated for your particular web page. I posted this answer anyway, as it might help others in a more general case.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox [has had a reader mode for a while](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Firefox-Reader-View-for-clutter-free-web-pages/ta-p/38466) - indicated by a book icon in the address bar. You can tap on it from any page to generate an easier to read, clutter free view

[image]

This also gives you a reasonable amount of flexibility over overall width, font sizes, and line spacing, as well as three themes.